# Create Gcovr standalone version

Tags: mingw, gcov, gcovr

I have a question about gcovr.
Is it possible to install or create a standalone version of the gcovr.
So that the user doesn't need to instal python or gcovr ?
So that i just have to add the path. (executable)

Thanks for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only supported way to install gcovr is via `pip`, as shipped with Python 3. This requirement is somewhat reasonable since gcovr will generally be used on developer or CI systems that have loads of additional stuff installed.

Nevertheless, you might be able to create your own standalone gcovr packages. For example, you could likely create a standalone executable using [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).